# The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

When I'm not logged in and I'm logged in it's no problem.
But if I'm already logged in and I close the app and open it again. My app is showing this problem.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ════════════════
The getter 'auth' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: auth
The relevant error-causing widget was
ThreadItem
lib\threadMain.dart:37
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

and this is my code

**profile.dart**

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUser(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return displayUserInformation(context, snapshot);
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            )
```

**provider.dart**

```
class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AuthService auth;

  Provider({Key key, Widget child, this.auth}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }

  static Provider of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider>();
}
```

Comment: Share the code for the widget `ThreadItem`, line number 37 in threadMain. The possible reason is that you are using auth there which has a value of null, therefore, check where are you initialising the value for auth.

Comment: return ThreadItem(data: data,myData: widget.myData,updateMyDataToMain: widget.updateMyData,threadItemAction: _moveToContentDetail,isFromThread:true,commentCount: data['postCommentCount'],parentContext: context,);

Comment: Is it possible to forget to include auth here?

Comment: This is not helpful. Edit your question, paste screenshot threadMain.dart & where you are setting the value of auth in your code base.

Comment: Rather than using FutureBuilder in `profile.dart`, use this `User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;` to get the current user data